# Ktor HttpClient handling close in multiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

According to the [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/client.html#close-client), we should call close method after we are done with http client instance. What is the right way to handle the close method of ktor http client in multiplatform env. ? In my case, I have a KMM project with android and ios. I am using HttpClient in common source set.

Or maybe the close method should be handled by specific applications instead of the multiplatform lib?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? You can simply call `client.close()` on demand.

Comment: The `close` method is available in the common source set.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov , I mean how do I get notified from an Android/IOs application that the application is closing? If I want to reuse http client while the application is active and close it when the application closes, how can I do this in common source set?

Comment: For Android, you can define an `onDestroy` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy() method on the `MainActivity` that is called before an activity is destroyed. Btw, why do you need to close a client if resources will be freed anyway?